# Black screen in navigation controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I am unable to see the view controller in my navigation controller.

Currently a user saves some information and I want to push them to the start of the app again.

I am doing this programatically.

Currently for what I have below, the navigation controller is displayed but the view controller is not.

```
SubclassConfigViewController *nextViewController = [[SubclassConfigViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];            
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:nextViewController];
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Any help anyone can provide is greatly appreciated! :-)

Comment: What are really up to? Your SubclassConfigViewController is being initWithNibName:nil, which essentially means no valid nib file. Then how do you expect to see something on screen?

Comment: @AyanSengupta - That's what I thought. I am using storyboards so no nib's (I believe). So I then tried the init method and still no luck. I simply what to go back to the rootviewcontroller. Any thoughts?

Comment: For storyboard you can not initiate a VC like something you have done as it does not use initWithNibName to load its views from a XIB. Instead you need to implement `-(void)prepareForSegue: sender:` method in your source view controller and inside this method you can get a hold of the target view controller with `segue.destinationViewController` property that returns the reference of the destination view controller if that segue is performed.

Comment: Hi I'm currently trying to do the same thing why can't I create a subclassconfigviewcontroller object?

Comment: That is the name of my viewController. You would replace mine with what ever yours is. Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a storyboard you should be using this:

```
SubclassConfigViewController *nextViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Next"];
```

Make sure you give the controller an identifier in IB, and pass that string in the method.

Comment: Well, if the VC is not linked to any segue in the storyboard, this is essentially the one and only way

Comment: Great. Thanks! Funny thing was I had that line before and changed it for what was the incorrect syntax. rdelmar, you've been a great help!